# ¿Cómo puedo comparar los datos de una array entre sí?

Tags: c#

El problema es almacenar números aleatorios (10) en una array , después quiero sacar esos números por consola pero solo los números no repetidos y además decir cuantas veces se ha repetido dicho numero ejemplo:

Ejemplo: Si los números aleatorios generados son:
1, 7, 10, 2, 1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 5

La salida del programa será la siguiente:
Números: 1 2 3 5 7 10

Repeticiones :3 2 1 1 2 1

Mi gran duda es como puedo comparar los números y además contar las repeticiones , os dejo mi código por si sirve de ayuda , muchas gracias.

```
class Program
{
    // Imprime array pasada por parámetros y el tamaño( por si las veces de imprimir no son todas de l array) 
    public static void PrintNumbers(int[] arrayToPrint , int size)
    {
        //CONSTANTES
        //VARIABLES
        //ENTRADAS
        //PROCESOS
        //SALIDAS
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine($"Numeros aleatorios : {arrayToPrint[i]}");
        }
    }   
    //@OVERRIDE
    // Sobrecarga para imprimir 
    public static void PrintNumbers(int[] arrayToPrint)
    {
        //CONSTANTES
        //VARIABLES
        //ENTRADAS
        //PROCESOS
        //SALIDAS
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToPrint.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Numeros aleatorios : {arrayToPrint[i]}");
        }
    }
    // Genera numeros aleatorios entre MIN y MAX (se le pasa por parámetros el rango de valores) y los almacena en un array
    public static int[] GenerateNumbers(byte MIN, byte MAX, byte SIZE)
    {
        //CONSTANTES
        
        //VARIABLES
        Random ran = new Random();
        int[] numeros = new int[SIZE];
        //ENTRADAS
        // NUMEROS ALEATORIOS GENERADOS
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++)
        {
            numeros[i] = ran.Next(MIN, MAX);             
        }
        //PROCESOS
        Array.Sort(numeros); // ordenos los numeros aleatorios de menor a mayor
        //SALIDAS
        return numeros;
    }

    public static void CalculateNumbers(int[] numeros, byte SIZE)
    {
        //CONSTANTES
        //VARIABLES
        bool test = true;
        int counter = 0;
        int z = 1;
        
        int[] newNumeros = new int[SIZE]; // almacenar los valores unicos de los numeros aleatorios 

        //ENTRADAS
        //PROCESOS
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                if (numeros[i] == numeros[j]) // si el numero 1º es igual al 2 
                {
                    newNumeros[j] += 1; // sumamos 1 en nuestra 1º posicion del contador 


                }

            }
        }

      

        //SALIDAS
        PrintNumbers(numeros);
        Console.WriteLine("************************");
        PrintNumbers(newNumeros);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //CONSTANTES
        const byte MIN = 1; // Rango numero aleatorio minimo
        const byte MAX = 11;// Rango numero aleatorio máximo
        const byte SIZE = 10;

        //VARIABLES


        //ENTRADAS

        //PROCESOS          
        CalculateNumbers(GenerateNumbers(MIN, MAX,SIZE),SIZE);

        //SALIDAS
        

       






    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();
int[] numeros = new int[10];
int min = 1;
int max = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   numeros[i] = r.Next(min, max + 1);
}

var numerosAgrupados = (from n in numeros
                        group n by n into grupo
                        select new
                        {
                           Numero = grupo.Key,
                           Repeticiones = grupo.Count()
                        }).OrderByDescending(n => n.Repeticiones).ToList();

foreach (var n in numerosAgrupados)
{
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", n.Numero, n.Repeticiones));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Para lograr lo que quieres puedes hacer uso de **Linq**.

Lo primero que se hace es declarar las variables:

**r:** variable de tipo **Random** encargada de la generación de los números aleatorios.

**numeros:** es un arreglo de tipo **int** de **10** posiciones donde se guardarán los números aleatorios generados.

**min** y **max**: son variables de tipo **int** que indican el limite inferior y superior del rango de generación de los números aleatorios.

Después se ejecuta un **ciclo for** para generar los números aleatorios en el rango especificado y guardarlos en el **arreglo numeros**.

Posteriormente haciendo uso de **Linq** se ejecuta una consulta que agrupará los números y contará la cantidad de veces que este se repite, devolviendo una lista ordenada descendentemente por la cantidad de repeticiones de los números. Cada elemento de esta lista será un objeto anónimo de dos propiedades: **propiedad Numero** de tipo **int** y **propiedad Repeticiones** de tipo **int**.

Por último mediante un **foreach** se imprimirá el resultado deseado que está almacenado en la **variable numerosAgrupados**.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

**Nota:** Analiza este código y adáptalo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias , me ha venido de lujo!!